# Skip search and replace after a heading in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have to replace a pattern, but I don't want to replace it after a particular word.

This is my program:

```
:vnoremap   ::silent! call Bib()

function! Bib()
   %s/\s*\n*{\\&}\s*\n*/ /g
   %s/\([A-Z]\)\.\([A-Z]\)\./\1\. \2\./g
   "%s/\(\w*\-\w*\|\w*\),\s*\n*\([A-Z]\)\./\r\\snm{\1}\r\2\./g 

endfunc
```

I don't want this search pattern after a particular a word: "References"

Answer (score 1):

To match "something", but not after a specific "word", you can use `\@<!`;

`/\(word\)\@<! something/`

For replacing "something" by "somethingelse", but only if "something" is not after "word":

`:%s/\(word\)\@<! something/ somethingelse/`

From inside `vim`, show the description with `:help /\@<!`:

```
\@<!    Matches with zero width if the preceding atom does NOT match just
    before what follows.  Thus this matches if there is no position in the
    current or previous line where the atom matches such that it ends just
    before what follows.  |/zero-width| {not in Vi}
    Like "(?<!pattern)" in Perl, but Vim allows non-fixed-width patterns.
    The match with the preceding atom is made to end just before the match
    with what follows, thus an atom that ends in ".*" will work.
    Warning: This can be slow (because many positions need to be checked
    for a match).  Use a limit if you can, see below.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `%` for a whole file replace, you could try with a [range](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges) for the address:

```
0,/^References$/s/\s*\n*{\\&}\s*\n*/ /g
0,/^References$/s/\([A-Z]\)\.\([A-Z]\)\./\1\. \2\./g
0,/^References$/s/\(\w*\-\w*\|\w*\),\s*\n*\([A-Z]\)\./\r\\snm{\1}\r\2\./g
```

(Assumes that `References` is the only word in the line. Modify the regex as needed.)

Comment: how to replace it after the word References and the remaining part safe

Comment: @sam that is, from the line containing `References` to the end of the document? The address range would be `/References/,$`, I think.